# How to make a background image appear over a gradient background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to configure this jquery table sorter to have arrows when its clicked.  The problem I am having is that my  column has a gradient background and the background image will not appear over the gradient.  It will work when i use a plain "background-color:#000000"

Any idea how to make it appear over the gradient like it appears over a plain background color?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: is your gradient background an image?

Answer (score 3):

A background gradient is considered an image by your browser. So, when you set the background image to something else, it is being overridden.

You can however pile background images one on top of the other:

http://jsfiddle.net/SjG9R/